# ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am new to C# and I have been trying to create a login using ADO.NET and WinForm but when I try logging in I get this error.

How do I solve this problem?

```
if (txtpassword.Text != string.Empty || txtusername.Text != string.Empty)
            {

                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from LoginTable where username='" + txtusername.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", cn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    this.Hide();
                    Home home = new Home();
                    home.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("No Account avilable with this username and password ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

Comment: *I get this error.* - What's the error? Also your code is currently open to SQL Injection so you might want to look into that too.

Comment: Did you try searching SO for your error message?   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ExecuteReader%3A+Connection+property+has+not+been+initialized

Comment: @Izzy I did an edit as I thought it would be hidden by formatting (easily done for a first question) - no, it's the error in the title

Comment: SqlCommand class is designed to work with ms sql server and not with mysql, therefore removed mysql tag. Not clear though what this question has to do with any database server as the error comes from .Net, not from a database server.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [SqlCommand Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

you need to open your connection first.

```
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from LoginTable where username='" + txtusername.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", cn);

            cn.open(); //

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                dr.Close();

                cn.close(); //

                this.Hide();
                Home home = new Home();
                home.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                dr.Close();
                cn.close(); //
                MessageBox.Show("No Account avilable with this username and password ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```